# ssis expression how to convert datetime sql statement?

Tags: ssis

In ssis package I have `String type variable V2` inside expression property i'm writing following sql query

`"select * from mytable where date = " + @[System::StartTime]`

But it is giving me an error :

```
The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Attempt to set the result type of binary operation ""select * from table where date = " + @[System::StartTime]" failed with error code 0xC0047080.
```

Even I have also tried with `(DT_WSTR) @[System::StartTime]`
still no luck any advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change data type of both StartTime variable and [date] field from the query to string.
Try this:

```
"select * from mytable where convert( varchar(10), [date], 120) = '" + SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)@[System::StartTime],1, 10) + "'"
```

Which should return a proper query:

```
select * from mytable where convert( varchar(10), [date], 120) = '2013-05-22'
```

`convert()` will give you string like "2013-05-22". In my system (DT_WSTR) cast on `@[System::StartTime]` is returning string "2013-05-22 16:14:43", but if you have other settings, you'd have to construct the string from dateparts, if your default result would be for example "05/22/2013 16:14:43" due to other regional setting.

What is the verion of sql server you are using? and [date] field type exactly?

Comment: token like `TOKEN((DT_WSTR,50)@[System::StartTime]," ",1)` instead of substring could be used as well.